# TFS - project lost from source control

Tags: tfs

I am having a problem trying to retreive a project from source control.
I have probably done the wrong thing removing bindings and so forth. The version of my project in source control is not the latest version.
I am wondering if it can be retreived from the SQL Server storage.
Alternatively is it possible to retreive it from converting back the live source code?

I shall try to explain what I did.
A project I have was in source control, but when I opened the project it was not locked. So I opened the project from source control, but it was an old project with the same name.
I tried unbinding the mapping, created a new workspace and extarcted to a new local folder. But I get the old project still.
I cannot find the latest version of the project.

Comment: Where _is_ the latest version?

Comment: I put more info. I cannot find the lastest version

Comment: If latest version never been in tfs, SQL or no SQL, you wont be able to get it back. As for source control - nothing is ever deleted, to force delete you must do so from sql using unsupported means, look in history maybe somebody rollbacked or overwrote your checkin. Otherwise it sounds like you have overwrote your local changes, still your statment is not very clear.